# WbDriverManager getDownloadedDriverVersion() returns null for firefox in Jenkins only

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

```
private static WebDriverManager webDriverManager;
webDriverManager = WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver();
webDriverManager.setup();
System.out.println("Printing downloadedDriverVersion: "+ webDriverManager.getDownloadedDriverVersion());
```

Please find above relevant code snippet. I am testing this bit of code locally for Firefox, Chrome and Edge which works as expected. This also works in jenkins for Chrome and Edge. However, it seems for firefox it isn't downloading the driver. Please find below the console output from Jenkins. Please could you suggest how to resolve this?

```
06:54:09.388 [INFO   ] WebDriverManager - Creating new FireFox driver
Mar 17, 2022 6:54:09 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities firefox
INFO: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`
06:54:09.434 [INFO   ] WebDriverManager - Using geckodriver 0.28.0 (resolved driver for Firefox 83)
06:54:09.464 [INFO   ] WebDriverManager - Using geckodriver 0.28.0 (resolved driver for Firefox 83)
06:54:09.475 [INFO   ] WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.gecko.driver as C:\Users\gtowfjenkins\.cache\selenium\geckodriver\win64\0.28.0\geckodriver.exe
Printing downloadedDriverVersion: null
Printing downloadedDriverPath: null
06:54:09.485 [INFO   ] WebDriverManager - Using geckodriver 0.28.0 (resolved driver for Firefox 83)
06:54:09.487 [INFO   ] WebDriverManager - Using geckodriver 0.28.0 (resolved driver for Firefox 83)
06:54:09.492 [WARN   ] ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'splunkSearchControllerContext' defined in file [c:\jenkins\workspace\workspace\WF\wf-technical-testing\wf-qa-adminUI_741\target\test-classes\com\broadridge\gto\wf\backend\contexts\SplunkSearchControllerContext.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webDriver' defined in com.broadridge.gto.wf.frontend.utilities.WebDriverManager: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'getDriver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of WebDriverManager.